# How do I change the structure of a time-series table from row to column?

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape, melt

So I have a table that is in the following format:

```
date <- c('t1','t1','t1','t2','t2','t2')
factor <- c('a','b','c','a','b','c')
beta <- c(1,2,4,3,5,2)

df <- data.frame(date, factor, beta)
df

 date factor beta
1   t1      a    1
2   t1      b    2
3   t1      c    4
4   t2      a    3
5   t2      b    5
6   t2      c    2
```

I want to reformat the data in the table in the following way:

```
date <- c('t1','t2')
factor_a <- c(1,3)
factor_b <- c(2,5)
factor_c <- c(4,9)

df <- data.frame(date, factor_a, factor_b, factor_c)

df
  date factor_a factor_b factor_c
1   t1        1        2        4
2   t2        3        5        9
```

I tried to use melt and reshape but I haven't been successful.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `spread`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   mutate(factor = paste0("factor_", factor)) %>%
   spread(factor, beta)
#    date factor_a factor_b factor_c
#1   t1        1        2        4
#2   t2        3        5        2
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, since I'm applying this to a different data frame than the simple example above. I'm getting this error: Error: Column `factor` can't be modified because it's a grouping variable.

Comment: @ErwinRhine  Can you do `df %>% ungroup %>% mutate(..`